# Add view permission from /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=course . Role is Author

Tags: wordpress, roles

When i set author role from user, in my custom post type view list can't access that user. 
But i can edit single customposttype, but no access customposttype list in admin page.

I try use plugin, but problem is stay actual.
[s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5QPy.png)

Comment: (Check the way you tried to embed a pixel raster, and access to that image. I only see black-on-white arrangement reading `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`. Find a more descriptive alternative text than `s`.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I don't have access in this area of admin page because, when register admin menu, i give access only ***administrator*** role.

```
add_menu_page(
                'Academist LMS',       // The value used to populate the browser's title bar when the menu page is active
                'Academist LMS',       // The text of the menu in the administrator's sidebar
                'administrator',  // What roles are able to access the menu
                'academist_lms_menu', // The ID used to bind submenu items to this menu
                '',               // The callback function used to render this menu
                $academist_elated_global_Framework->getSkin()->getSkinURI() . '/assets/img/admin-logo-icon.png', // Icon For menu Item
                10                // Position
            );
```

Change administrator role in to your role. Or get current user role. 
This file i found in my theme core plugin.